# How to let the user define the function - Python - Bisection Method

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I have written the following code to find the roots of an equation using the bisection method.

```
def f(x):
    return x**3-5

#computes f(x) intercept with the bisection method
#err - a small floating number that tells you your accuracy
def bisection(low, high, err):
    mid = (high+low)/2   

    while(abs(f(mid)) > err):
        print ('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'mid= ', mid)
        if f(mid) > 0:
            high = mid
        elif f(mid) < 0:
            low = mid
        mid = (high + low)/2
    return mid

print (bisection(0, 100, 0.001))
```

The code executes the method without a problem. However, I would like to find a way to prompt the user to input their own equations to solve rather than it already pre-programmed.

I appreciate any input you have.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: use [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sympy import *
eqn=sympify(input('Eqn'))
f=lambda x:eqn.subs({'x':x})
```

Comment: I'd add a line to input a string for the user to input an equation to solve. Then use this string as the argument of sympify instead of 'x**3 - 5'.

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt the user for coefficients for a polynomial:

```
print('a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d')
a = input('>a')
b = input('>b')
c = input('>c')
d = input('>d')
```

and then you input this into the function:

```
def f(x, a, b, c, d):
     return a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c * x + d
```

A better way (continuing from @SmartManoj 's answer):

```
from sympy import *
equation = input('Your equation > ')
eqn=sympify(equation)
f=lambda x:eqn.subs({'x':x})
```

If you're using python 2, use `raw_input('Your equation > ')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for Sympy, `eval` is native.

```
def f(expr, x)
  return eval(expr)

for i in range(10):
  print f("x * x", i)
```